Python dateutil is being inconsistent with American vs British date formats
I am using the dateutil library with its 'fuzzy' ability to parse dates out of strings. It seemed to be actually quite good at it but on careful inspection it was jumping back and forth between British and American date formats in reading in, namely whether the middle number is a month (British) or a day (American)
The following code will demo what is happening, to make the output more readable and obvious, I am converting the output from datetime to date then to isoformat dates.
from dateutil.parser import parse

def customparse(x):
    return parse(x, fuzzy=True, ignoretz=True).date().isoformat()

a = "Yorkshire Terrier 13-06-2013a.pdf"
b = "09-10-2014-spaniel.pdf"

print(a, "      ", customparse(a))
print(b, "      ", customparse(b))

output:
Yorkshire Terrier 13-06-2013a.pdf        2013-06-13
09-10-2014-spaniel.pdf        2014-09-10

In each case the British format is intended which it correctly picks in the first one as it is obvious, no 13th month of the year, but then it decides to go with the American format for the second one.
Does anyone know how to tame its behaviour and make it be consistent?

That's not inconsistent - it's parsing month first if that's plausible, because the default of dayfirst is False. Read the docs, and pick a different value if that's not what you want.

A library like pandas has slightly better inference, looking at more values in the column. But you would do no better if you were only given one value at a time, and once you choose a format, you're stuck. If you don't require the full flexibility of parse for each instance, but only need to test for a few formats, consider a strategy where you try these formats as part of a regex, and sticking with a successful one (or starting over when you find a conflict, with the next one). If you do need this level of flexibilty, how would you know what "10-09-14-german-sheppard" even is?

Just to double down on @jonrsharpe comment: See what parse("Yorkshire Terrier 11-06-2013a.pdf", fuzzy=True, ignoretz=True).date().isoformat() does. And then parse("Yorkshire Terrier 11-06-2013a.pdf", fuzzy=True, dayfirst=True, ignoretz=True).date().isoformat()

@Grismar yearfirst also defaults to False, so that would be 2014-09-10 (i.e. MM-DD-YY) unless configured otherwise.

If you know that a date in the string is in British format, why not identify it using a regular expression? Then you can convert to a datetime object without any need for fuzzy logic and thus avoid any ambiguity

Thanks @jonrsharpe that was easy to fix!
def customparse(x):
    return parse(x, fuzzy=True, ignoretz=True, dayfirst=True).date().isoformat()

